# Regex expression for password rules

Tags: regex

I have a requirement for password rules. Following are the rules.

The password must follow the following guidelines:

- Be at least eight characters long
- Contain 3 of these 4 options: lower case letter, upper case letter, number, or special character
- When user specifies a password that does not meet the above rules, return message stating:

  Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain 3 of the 4 following options:

  - Lower case letter (a-z)
  - Upper case letter (A-Z)
  - Number (0-9)
  - Special character (!@#$%^&')

Please help me to get a regex expression to handle above conditions.

i appreciate all your help. following is the solution for my requirement

```
if(password.matches("^(?=.*[0-9]).{1,}$")){
validCount++;
}
if(password.matches("^(?=.*[a-z]).{1,}$")){
validCount++;
}
if(password.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z]).{1,}$")){
validCount++;
}
if(password.matches("^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{1,}$")){
validCount++;
}
return validCount >= 3 ? true : false;
```

Thanks,
Ramki

Comment: I think it would make more sense to do this without regexes... Or with 4 separate regexes (check for 3 matches out of 4).

Comment: I would do this with 4 separate regexes and check that 3 of 4 match like jahroy said. 8 characters long is just check `strPassword.Length >= 8`

Comment: There are dozens of hits in a search here for `[regex] password`. Since you've apparently tried nothing on your own, perhaps a review of those will get you started. :) Start with the `Related` list on the right side of this page.

Comment: Not a real question? Pattern matching is what regexes were made for.

Answer (score 11):

This is, if you want an elegant regex, as close as you can get

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&'])[^ ]{8,}$
```

The basic idea is to use a technique called "positive lookahead" :

```
(?=.*PutHereWhatYouWantToAllow)
```

Your extra requirement 3 out of 4 is not easy to solve with regexes cause you cannot make them count basically.
You could write out the necessary permutations of the above regex (tell me if it doesn't make sense) but that would make a very long regex.
What you could do is write out the permutations in code so that the regex stays maintainable since you are not repeating the patterns literally.

I'll have a shot if I you tell me your language (C#?) cause it's a good challenge.

**Update 1**

Here is the regex that will match at least 3 of your requirements (4 is also allowed), just for the challenge of it. Don't use this in production but loop in the language with individual regexes as mentioned in the comments.

> ^((?=.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[\d])|(?=.*[a-z].*[\d].*[A-Z])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[a-z].*[\d])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[\d].*[a-z])|(?=.*[\d].*[a-z].*[A-Z])|(?=.*[\d].*[A-Z].*[a-z])|(?=.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[a-z].*[!@#$%^&'].*[A-Z])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[a-z].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[!@#$%^&'].*[a-z])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[a-z].*[A-Z])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[A-Z].*[a-z])|(?=.*[a-z].*[\d].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[a-z].*[!@#$%^&'].*[\d])|(?=.*[\d].*[a-z].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[\d].*[!@#$%^&'].*[a-z])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[a-z].*[\d])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[\d].*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[\d].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[A-Z].*[!@#$%^&'].*[\d])|(?=.*[\d].*[A-Z].*[!@#$%^&'])|(?=.*[\d].*[!@#$%^&'].*[A-Z])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[A-Z].*[\d])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&'].*[\d].*[A-Z]))[^ ]{8,}$

**Update 2**

This is the approach to take in java

From the comments I read that you are testing like the following

- lowercase "^[a-z]*$";
- uppercase "^[A-Z]*$";
- digits="^[0-9]*$";

I don't think you are on the right track here. The lowercase will only report success if *all* characters are lowercase, and not just one. Same remark for the rest.

These are the 4 individual regexes of which at least 3 should report a match

```
[a-z]
[A-Z]
\d
[!@#$%^&']
```

Here is the test that the password should not contain a space

```
^[^ ]*$
```

The test for at least 8 characters

```
.{8,}
```

So I split the requirements and not combine them. This should make for more readable code especially if one starts with regexes.

Comment: It says that it has to have 3 of the 4 options.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. i forgot to mention, it should not accept white space chars.i need not to check for all 4 conditions. any 3 of them enough. i am not sure how to put conditions (AND OR) in regex.

Comment: @Ramki I updated the regex so it rejects passwords with a space. Regexes are not programming language so they don't support AND and OR although you can emulate most if not all conditions in it. But it cannot say 3 out of 4 as explained in my answers. Best to do the permutations in code.

Comment: i tried following   String newRegex ="((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&']).{8,40})";

Comment: @Ramki I'm not fluent in Java but you get the idea to do it yourself hopefully.

Comment: It might make sense to use 4 different regexes.  You could test for matches on all four of them.  As soon as you get three matches, you have success. This would be so much easier to read and no less efficient.

Comment: @Ramki - You're going to have to play around with escape characters to get your regex to work (this will be a good exercise in learning regexes).  For example, you might have to escape parentheses and/or braces.  Breaking the regexes into 4 pieces will also simplify this task a great deal.  Start simple and enjoy the learning process!

Comment: i think your suggestion will save a lot of time. i will put 4 different expressions. thanks for your quick reply

Comment: No problem. Testing all 4 requirements in a java loop and stopping as soon as 3 are matched seems much more maintanable than do it in one monster regex. But I can't help myself and will post that big regex later.

Comment: i am trying to check for lowercase letters. is this correct?
"(?=.*[a-z])"

Comment: Added the monster regex to make the point it's too big of a regex if you want to do it in 1 shot

Comment: it looks like very big expression. as you said, i would like to go with individual expressions for each.i posted all 4 individual expressions. could you please validate them.

Comment: There are multiple regex validators/sandboxes available on the web.  It looks like the regexes you've supplied are not quite correct.  For example ^[a-z]*$ would match a string that contains ONLY lowercase letters.  You want to make sure it contains ANY lowercase letter, so you don't need the anchors (the ^ and $).

Comment: @Ramki Updated the answer to guide you with the java coding.

Comment: @Ramki modified the regexes in update 2 to make them more efficient (old versions are ok too)

Comment: @gdoron Maybe you are right. Still, I think he's eager to learn and I had nothing better to do :) If he absorbs all our thinking he'll soon be at a good level. Learning regexes has a very steep learning curve. You should actually start with a book instead of throwing yourself which works for other technologies.

Comment: i really appreciate your help. i came up with followng solution.
[code] public static boolean validatePassword(String password){
        int validCount = 0;
        if(password.matches("^(?=.*[0-9]).{1,}$")){
            validCount++;
        }
        if(password.matches("^(?=.*[a-z]).{1,}$")){
            validCount++;
        }
        if(password.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z]).{1,}$")){
            validCount++;
        }
        if(password.matches("^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{1,}$")){
            validCount++;
        }
        return validCount >= 3 ? true : false;
    }
[/code]

Comment: hello Ramki. Its best to add your solution to the question itself as it will show the code better formatted. Glad to hear you solved it

Comment: Muhaha! I don't recommend that regex at all. It's a composition but on that's better expressed if mixed with imperative code. That's where regexes shine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidatePassword
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String pw = "abaslkA3FLKJ";

        // create an array with 4 regex patterns

        Pattern [] patternArray = {
            Pattern.compile("[a-z]"),
            Pattern.compile("[A-Z]"),
            Pattern.compile("[0-9]"),
            Pattern.compile("[&%$#]")
        };

        int matchCount = 0;

        // iterate over the patterns looking for matches

        for (Pattern thisPattern : patternArray) {
            Matcher theMatcher = thisPattern.matcher(pw);        
            if (theMatcher.find()) {
                matchCount ++;
            }
        }

        if (matchCount >= 3) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Failure: only " + matchCount + " matches");
        }
    }
}
```

I only added a few *special characters* to the 4th pattern... You'll have to modify it for your needs.  You may need to escape certain characters with a backslash.  You may also want to add other constraints like checking for no spaces.  I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Regarding the special characters to the 4th pattern. You don't need to escape any of them according to the regex rules (and java for that matter). They only thing to watch out for is that you don't put the ^ first since that would negate the character class.

Comment: Thanks.  I know that none of those need escape chars.  Not sure about whatever characters the OP ends up adding.  Didn't feel like testing all possibilities...

Comment: @jahroy i really appreciate your help.