# regex not validating

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex for password validation in javascript:

```
^[!#\$%\(\)\*,\-\./:;=\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}~a-zA-Z0-9]*$

   <script type="text/javascript">
        var regex = "^[!#\$%\(\)\*,\-\./:;=\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}~a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        var value = 'test';
        if (value.match(regex) == false) {
            alert('password invalid');
        }
    </script>
```

The regex rules are:

- 12-25 characters
- at least one upper case letter
- at least one lower case letter
- at least one numeric digit
- at least one of the special  characters: !#$%()*,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~

However, the regex doesn't seem to work. It matches any characters. How do I fix this?

Comment: First up, I don't see anywhere in that regex which enforces a 12-25 character limit. You seem to have just used * which means '0 or more' - your current regex just reads:

Start -- Any number of characters from your four bullet points (including 0) -- End

Comment: split your regex into 3 regexs with check all rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using positive lookahead your regex can be validated in one single match call. Use this regex:

```
 var regex =
     /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!#$%()\*,/:;=?@\[\\\]\^_`{}|.-])^.{12,25}$/;
 var value = 'aaaAaaaaa?test2';
 if (!value.match(regex))
     document.writeln('invalid');
 else
     document.writeln('valid');
```

[`See this code live in action`](http://jsfiddle.net/FYtSy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){1})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[!#$%()*,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~ ]){1,}).{12,25}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-|^!#$%()*,./:;=?@_`{}~[\]]).{12,25}$
```

It uses the technique of lookahead to make sure there is at least 1 digit, lowercase char, ...

Also, look at [Regex expression for password rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729347/regex-expression-for-password-rules/10729398#10729398) for a similar challenge