# Need to build regex to validate password field

Tags: javascript, regex

Password must be between 8 - 12 characters. Password must include **three** of the following: Upper case letter, lower case letter, number and special character: ! @ # $ % ^ * ~ : ; & > < [ ] { } | - _ + = ?

I have tried below code but I was only able to validate-
To allow 8-12 characters However I was NOT able to filter this regex to include any three of the following characters- 
Upper case letter, lower case letter, number and special character.

Code snippet tried:

```
var pass = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?]{8,32}/;
if("Tesst@###123".match(pass)) {
  console.log("valid");
} else {
  console.log("NOT valid");
}
```

Comment: Please search for one of the 1000 questions here on SO about password validation.

Comment: Have a look here, and this should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204836/regex-to-find-3-out-of-4-conditions

Comment: Perhaps this could help: [http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Does this mean [correcthorsebatterystaple](https://xkcd.com/936/) won't pass?

Comment: Take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10729398/5378536

Comment: Doing all this as a single expression is probably not the best approach.

Comment: Here i buit regex which will allow minimum 3 of the following- 
- UPPERCASE
-lowercase
-numbers 1
- some of the special characters.
 /((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?])(?!.*[()\`\\/\"\'/.',])(?!.*\s).{8,32})|((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*[()\`\\/\"\'/.',])(?!.*\s).{8,32})|((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?])(?!.*[()\`\\/\"\'/.',])(?!.*\s).{8,32})|((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?])(?!.*[()\`\\/\"\'/.',])(?!.*\s).{8,32})|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^*~:;&><\[\]{}|\-_+=?])(?!.*[()\`\\/\"\'/.',])(?!.*\s).{8,32})/